# Normalization of log-returns or normalization of cumulative log-returns

Tags: normalization, standardization, rms, nls

This questions seeks for discussion to find theoretical support for normalizing cumulative log-returns vs normalizing log-returns

By "normalizing" (also known as standarizing) I mean it in the statistical sense, where we subtract the mean and divide by the square root of the variance of a random variable, i.e. $$ Z = \frac{Y - \mathbb{E}(Y)}{\sqrt{Var(Y)}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Background:

I am working on a Nonlinear Least Squares problem, where the objective function to be minimized is the sum of squared errors. In simple:

$$ \min_{\theta} \quad (Y_t - \hat{Y}_t)'(Y_t - \hat{Y}_t)$$

where $Y_t$ is the observed log-returns and $\hat{Y}_t$ are the returns produced by the model. Both are of size $n \times 1$. $\theta$ is a $d$ dimensional vector that contains the parameters to be estimated. $d$ is usually low (no larger than 10) and there are 2 hyperparameters to be tuned.

In all setups, I use log-returns to compute the sum of squared errors and to fit the model.

Issue:

In the past, I have usually normalized **log-returns** to enhance the gaussian qualities of data. This has proven to contribute to better convergence of optimizers, stability of estimates, etc.

In my current setup, I estimate the **same model on the same data** several times and using Root Mean Squared Errors (RMSE) to pick the best fit for hyperparameter tunning of the two aforementioned parameters. Finally, I pick the specification with the Lowest RMSE

This criterion **fails miserably** when it comes to pick the best fit. I have tried several other permutations (use log-returns, minmax standarization, relative RMSE, you name it)

*However*, I found that, when I:

1. Estimate the model with log-returns and get $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{Y}_t$,
2. Compute the **cumulative log-returns** of $Y^c_t=cumsum(Y_t)$ and    $\hat{Y}_t^c=cumsum(\hat{Y}_t$
3. Compute the residuals as $\varepsilon_t = Y^c_t - \hat{Y}_t^c$
4. Compute the RMSE as $RMSE = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^N {\varepsilon_t}^2}$
5. Select the specification with the lowest RMSE

the procedure picks the **BEST** fit consistently, not only for 1 day but for all days and different type of stocks

Question:

I found counterintuitive that the methodology presented above works. Because of the following:

- Usually we use log-returns as the random variable to be modelled,
- Both my model and the data produce the same scale of variables (i.e. log-returns), so using log-returns directly *should work*

However, the residuals computed this way look normal

Here, I am trying to (i) understand why the second approach works and(ii) whether there is theoretical support for the second approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "normalization" as described here does not change anything about gaussian properties of the data.  It's just centering/ scaling;  heavy tails and skew are the same as before.  Also what do you mean with "it picks the best fit " : visually?  How do you determine best fit other than by your target metric that you optimize for? Any chance to share a reproducible example here ( code, data, simulated data)?